# How to subtract a number from all elements in a DataFrame with pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, series, subtraction

I'm trying to subtract a number from all elements in a DataFrame with pandas. However, only the 1st element is subtracted and the others get `NaN`.

Here's the data:
DataFrame_3x5.csv

```
A   B   C
0.1 0.3 0.5
0.2 0.4 0.6
0.3 0.5 0.7
0.4 0.6 0.8
0.5 0.7 0.9
```

Here's my code:

```
import pandas as pd
data = pd.read_csv(r"DataFrame_3x5.csv")
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
medianList = pd.DataFrame()

for i in range(0, data.shape[1]):
  medianList = medianList.append([df.iloc[:,i].median()], ignore_index=True)

for i in range(0, data.shape[1]):
  print(data.iloc[:,i])
  print(medianList.iloc[i])
  print(data.iloc[:,i] - medianList.iloc[i])
  # print(data.iloc[:,i].sub([medianList.iloc[i]], axis='columns')) # doesn't work
```

Here's the result:

```
0    0.1
1    0.2
2    0.3
3    0.4
4    0.5
Name: A, dtype: float64
0    0.3
Name: 0, dtype: float64
0   -0.2
1    NaN
2    NaN
3    NaN
4    NaN
dtype: float64
0    0.3
1    0.4
2    0.5
3    0.6
4    0.7
Name: B, dtype: float64
0    0.5
Name: 1, dtype: float64
0   -0.2
1    NaN
2    NaN
3    NaN
4    NaN
dtype: float64
0    0.5
1    0.6
2    0.7
3    0.8
4    0.9
Name: C, dtype: float64
0    0.7
Name: 2, dtype: float64
0   -0.2
1    NaN
2    NaN
3    NaN
4    NaN
dtype: float64
```

My expectation:

```
0   -0.2
1   -0.1
2    0.0
3    0.1
4    0.2
```

According to [this site](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.subtract.html),

```
print(data.iloc[:,i].sub([medianList.iloc[i]], axis='columns'))
```

... should work, but actually it produces an error:

```
ValueError: No axis named columns for object type <class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>
```

I don't know what to do any more. Please help me. Thank you.

Comment: you could just do `df - your_number` ?

Comment: can you add expected output

Comment: @AyoubZAROU I believe that's what I'm doing at `data.iloc[:,i] - medianList.iloc[i]` (Not sure, though). For the expected output, please look at **My Expectation**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you could do:

```
df - df.median(axis=0)
```

and pandas would take care of the axis used to compute the values

Comment: You're my life saver. Oh, man, I didn't even have to calculate medians column by column using a for-loop. You've solved my problem with a single line of code. I have to learn more about pandas. Thank you very much!

Comment: glad I could help, happy coding ^^

Answer (score 1):

A simple solution:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv(r"DataFrame_3x5.csv")

df['A'] - df['A'].median()
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think if you first try `dropna` and then simply subtract it can work

```
df=df.dropna(how='any')
df['Sub']=int(df['A']) - int(df['B']) - int(df['C'])
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd
data = pd.read_csv(r"DataFrame_3x5.csv")
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
medianList = pd.DataFrame()
for i in range(0, data.shape[1]):
  medianList = medianList.append([df.iloc[:,i].median()], ignore_index=True)

df1 = pd.DataFrame(columns=['A'])
j=0
for i in range(0, data.shape[0]):
    print(data['A'].iloc[i]) # one column
    print(medianList.iloc[i])  #1 value
    print(data['A'].iloc[i] - medianList.iloc[j])
```